# Two Drag and Drop Actions Running Simultaneously

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code:

```
a = driver.Findelement(By.XPath("Element1")));
b = driver.Findelement(By.XPath("Element2")));
Thread.Sleep(3000);               
action.ClickAndHold(a).MoveToElement(b).Release().Perform();
```

This drag and drop action performed well. But when other drag and drop actions try to run, The first action is also running.

Actually, my test case contains a sequence of drag and drop operations. While running the test case, the first drag and drop operations performed correctly, when the sequence comes to the second drag and drop operation, both (second and first drag and drop) actions are also executing (for ex: 1. Drag and drop the image 2. Drag and Drop the Data.  When a 2nd test case is performed simultaneously the first one also running. So that both DragnDrop execute simultaneously).

Due to this, my test case failed.

Note: Recently I have done a latest update on Nunit(3.10). Before that it was working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *The first action are also Performing*? can you give more details on what exactly is happening?

Comment: Actually my test case contains sequence of drag and Drop Operations, While Running the Testcase, First drag and drop operations performed correctly, When the sequence coming into second drag and drop operation, Both(second and first dragndrop) action are also performing.(for ex: 1. Drag and drop the image 2. Drag and Drop the Data.  When 2nd test case is perform simultaneously 1st one also Running. So that both DragnDrop working simultaneously)

Comment: Try to run with call back function, which means 2nd test waiting for first test complete